# Multiple inheritence using parent class method override

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, virtual-functions

Let's say I've got the following class hierarchy, wherein I have an interface and then further specializations of that interface that guarantee more functionality:

```
class parent_interface {
 public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class child1_interface : public parent_interface {
 public:
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class child2_interface : public parent_interface {
 public:
  virtual void baz() = 0;
}
```

And then I have concrete classes that provide that functionality:

```
class parent : public parent_interface {
 public:
  void foo() override;
};

class child1 : public parent, public child1_interface {
 public:
  //using parent::foo; ??
  void bar() override;
};
```

The problem is if I try to instantiate a child1 object, I get a compiler error that

> cannot declare field `instantiation_name` to be of abstract type because the following virtual functions are pure within child1:  void foo()

I can fix this by creating a method within child1 called foo, that just calls parent::foo, but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner solution to this problem.

Comment: You have a *diamond inheritance pattern*. If you search for e.g. `c++ diamond inheritance pattern` you should get plenty of hits about the problem with it, and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `virtual` inheritance, so that the compiler knows to combine the base classes back into one.  This should compile for you ([see it work](http://cpp.sh/6qyg4)):

```
class parent_interface {
 public:
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class child1_interface : public virtual parent_interface {
 public:
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class parent : public virtual parent_interface {
 public:
  void foo() override
  {
  }
};

class child1 : public parent, public child1_interface {
 public:
  //using parent::foo; ??
  void bar() override
  {
  }
};
```

For more information, you can read about [Virtual Base Classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class) here.

Comment: Ah, I had tried making child1_interface and child2_interface inherit parent_interface virtually, but I did not think to make parent virtually inherit from parent_interface.  Also, I don't think it is necessary to have child1 inherit virtually from parent and child1_interface.  Regular inheritance works fine.

Comment: You are correct about that.  You only need to specify `virtual` just before deriving from the interface.  I updated the code in my answer to reflect this.